# Alternative to SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter

Tags: java, spring, web-services, annotations, alternate

Now I use SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter for providing contract-last web service:

```
    @Component
@WebService(serviceName = "SampleService")
public class SampleEndpoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

    @WebMethod
    public ResponseBo getData(final RequestBo request) {
...

    }
}
```

Code in applicationContext.xml is small:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter">
<property name="baseAddress"
    value="http://localhost:8888/services/" />
```

*Spring’s SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter detects all @WebService annotated beans in the Spring application context, exporting them through the default JAX-WS server (the JDK 1.6 HTTP server).*

But my .war with those beans started on own server. How I can remove SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter and bind web serwice to server on which deployed .war?

P.S. I'm sorry for bad english.